# Using delete to prevent call with invalid values in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, factorial

I can use templates and delete facility to prevent calling factorial with character or float variables as follows. How to write the delete function for factorials with negative arguments?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T factorial(T n)
{
    return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1));
}

constexpr float factorial(double) = delete;
constexpr char factorial(char) = delete;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto fiveFactorial = factorial(5);
    constexpr auto point5fact = factorial(0.5); // Error. Call to deleted version
    constexpr auto letter5fact = factorial('5'); // DITTO
    constexpr auto minusFact = factorial(-1); // How to prevent this using delete?
}
```

Comment: You can't, since the value is evaluated a *runtime*. It's okay with the types, since they are known at the time of compilation, but you can't get compiler-errors for things that are only known at runtime. The only solution I can see is to make sure that `T` is an *unsigned* type.

Comment: As another possible solution, if you only want to allow unsigned integer types, is to only *declare* the generic function but not implement it (or maybe even mark it as deleted?). Then specialize the function for unsigned integer types with a definition (implementation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Impossible. `= delete` is a compile-time thing, while your arguments aren't always known at compile-time.

You could use `unsigned` parameter instead and remove all those deleted overloads, at the cost of being unable to call your function with signed numbers, like `factorial(2)`.

```
template <typename T> constexpr T factorial(T n)
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T, char>,
                  "Parameter type must be integral, unsigned, and not `char`.");
    return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : (n * factorial(T(n - 1)));
}
```

Comment: The OP's `factorial(5)` will no longer work with this, of course. If the OP is okay with that, fine, but I think it could use spelling out.

Comment: But now the implementation needs to be adapted: the recursive call must be `factorial(n - 1u)`, otherwise the call `factorial(5us)` (call with an unsigned short value 5) will fail, because `5us - 1` is of type `int`, which is not unsigned.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Done. :/

Answer (score 1):

> How to write the delete function for factorials with negative arguments?

You can't, since the value of the argument is a runtime property but you can only delete overloads based on types.

But since this is `constexpr`, there's another way - you just make the function ill-formed for negative inputs in a constant expression. For instance, by throwing. Also, since you tagged this C++14, I'm changing your implementation to be a loop:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T factorial(T n)
{
    if (n < 0) throw std::runtime_error("bad user!");

    T product = 1;
    for (T i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        product *= i;
    }
    return product;
}

constexpr auto good = factorial(5); // fine
constexpr auto bad = factorial(-1); // compile error because factorial(-1)
                                    // is not a valid constant expression
```